# Elasticsearch doesn't return results for a specific term search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am attempting to do a query where I filter on term for a specific term. This is the query I am attempting to run:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "tags": "sports"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "timestamp": "desc"
    }
}
```

When I run the same query with a different field `(ex: "type": "blog_post")` it works, so I am confident in the syntax.

I checked to make sure that `tags` was properly mapped (I checked at "http://server_name/index/_mapping") and it was.

I also checked that there are documents with `"tags" : "sports"` in Elasticsearch.

Any ideas what the issue could be? It is only that field, all others work, and `"tags"` is indexed.

Comment: Please add mapping description into the question. Also run GET index/{type}/{id} on a document you're expecting to find - to make sure the tags properly actually has the value you're looking for

Comment: you mentioned that you checked `"tags" : "sports"` in ES and matching documents was presents, how you check this ?

Comment: @yogesh just visually through kibana. When I run other queries I can see that "tags": "sports" is actually in the document, and I can see that kibana has the field indexed.

Comment: Also worth noting that when I run the query: tags:sports in kibana, it does return proper results, its only when I try to do the query in sense or in applications I'm writing where it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the mapping/analyzer you have defined for the field "tags"? If you have not defined any analyzer then it will be analysed using the standard analyzer which in turn will give stemmed token "sport" instead of "sports"

If you do a term search or term filter the input is not analyzed, and will try to search for an exact match. So search for term "sports" won't match.

You should either change the mapping for tags to "not_analyzed" or change the search query to something other than term, like [query string query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

Answer (score 0):

Based on a use case you've described I assume `tags` is mapped as an array of values. That said, [`term filter`](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/query-dsl-term-filter.html) can only be used for **exact matches**.

What I would try is to use [`terms filter`](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) or [`exist filter`](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/query-dsl-exists-filter.html) instead and change the query to this:

```
"terms" : { "tags" : "sports" }
```

or this

```
"exists" : { "tags" : "sports" }
```

Comment: When doing term searches looking for one item in an array
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "term" : {
                    "tags" : "sports"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

does work. I validated it be doing the same query on another index mapped to an array. I also tried "terms" and "tags":["sports"] but not luck with that either